# Micrsoft Excel Save to OneDrive -That location is not available when Network Disconnected

Tags: onedrive, microsoft-office-2016

I have Excel 2016 (I think - I can no longer get a simple Help About so I'm not sure) - This is a Home Use licensed version obtained using the company membership.

I also have a free OneDrive account where I store a few Excel files
The Entire OneDrive folder is synced to my local machine, so the Excel files are "Always" available  - however if I connect to a network with no internet connectivity I often get a problem where Excel says "That location is no longer available"  The location being "C:\Users\ross\OneDrive\Ross\Network"
and I can no longer save the Excel files to the oneDrive instead I have to save to My Documents and then copy them back to OneDrive

The Excel spreadsheet can still be opened by double clicking on "C:\Users\ross\OneDrive\Ross\Network\Network.xlsm"  Even when  I do this Excel will still refuse to save the file back to the location

I have tried turning off "Use Office applications to sync Office files that I Open" but this does not appear to help - I did not restart after doing this so maybe it will

On my Company laptop I have had a similar issue with loss of ability to save files. That is Office 365 and OneDrive for business however I have little control over the setup of that

I think it happens if I start editting whilst connected to the internet and then swap to a connection which is active but has no internet connectivity.
However in that case re-establising internet connectivity does not fix anything
In this case Excel does sometimes crash - and recover a file but still refuses to save to the local copy.

I also think it started after we upgraded to the Office which "Automatically saves" and has no File/Save menu option 
however the home version still has the Save option

As I make these sorts of connections regularly can anyone suggest what I could do to stop this failure?

In particular - How can I get office to (reliably) access the locally stored copies of the files with an active network - just without a connection to Microsoft cloud storage.

Answer (score -1):

You said it yourself: your problem arises when you connect to a network with no internet connectivity. That means that you cannot reach the internet from that network. And since you need the internet to connect to OneDrive, you can't sync your files if you don't have internet connectivity.

Comment: Well two problems first I don't need to sync the files are there and they are the latest and second when I do reconnect once the problem occurs it does not fix it.  It's some bug with office confusing the one drive local copy with a network location, but For my home computer I'll probably swap to the Google cloud storage as that is not integrated with office and so doesn't seem to be having the problem.